# Regarding cryonics, why can't you freeze a living body and then thaw it later, fully functional?

Tags: neuroscience, tissue

Cryonics is very popular in science fiction today, as a method of preserving animals, including humans, for long time storage and thawing the tissue later in the future. What is the difficulties with this method? Why can't we simply freeze living persons and expect them to be fully functional again later?

I've heard that the membrane potentials get lost in the process and thus all neural activity stops. I've also heard that freezing cells leads to cells imploding, due to the formation of ice crystals, leading to rapid necrosis. Is any of this true or just myths?